# how can I get a list of all image file from a directory by using DirectoryChooser in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I need to get all image file from a particular directory, and all images in all recursive subdirectory for this directory.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more and possibly edit your question so that it provides more details on what you are trying to accomplish and what steps and research you have already done to solve this problem for your self
Please consider looking at this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Files` API to get the image files:

```
Pattern imageMIMEPattern = Pattern.compile("image/.*");
button.setOnAction(evt -> {
    DirectoryChooser chooser = new DirectoryChooser();
    File f = chooser.showDialog(primaryStage);
    if (f != null) {
        Path p = f.toPath();
        try {
            // find all files with mime type image/... in subdirectories up to a depth of 10
            Files.find(p, 10, (path, attributes) -> {
                String contentType;
                try {
                    contentType = Files.probeContentType(path);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    return false;
                }
                return contentType != null && imageMIMEPattern.matcher(contentType).matches();
            }).forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Of course you need to replace `.forEach(System.out::println)` achieve the desired effect with the resulting `Stream<Path>` (e.g. map back to `File`/collect to `List`, ect.).

You also may want to use a different `BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes>` to determine the desired files. Furthermore you may want to search to a depth greater than 10.

If you want to follow links you need to add `FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS` as additional parameter to the [`Files.find` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-).